# Finding the largest frequent itemset

Tags: data-mining

Given a collection of itemsets `C`, and a support threshold `m`, is there an efficient way to generate the (or a) largest frequent pattern?

By frequent pattern I mean an itemset `p` such that the number of itemsets `s` in `C`, such that `p` is a subset of `s`, is at least `m`. By largest pattern I mean that the number of items in `p` should be as large as possible.

Specifically, I want to avoid generating the (combinatorially large) sets of all "maximal" or "closed" patterns -- any single pattern of maximum size will do.

Comment: What is wrong with APRIORI for this? Note that APRIORI does not compute the maximal or closed ones - it just computes all of them. But obviously you can forget the itemsets of `currentSize - 2`.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse : Apriori proceeds uses a breadth-first approach, so in terms of avoiding the generation of many patterns that is probably the worst idea. My objective is to get any maximally large pattern (doesn't matter which one) fast.

Comment: Actually it's not that bad. Because the number of candidate itemsets grows with the depth. By being able to prune the candidates to a minimum, you can cut down the the n times larger search space of the next level drastically. You can try to do a branch and bound version, though. B&B may help you to further reduce the candidates for this setting.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse : I mean that it's bad in this particular context, because I am looking for a frequent pattern of maximal size. Obviously by BFS we are generating *all* frequent patterns before we get to the largest one, which is precisely what I want to avoid.

Comment: How are you going to know there is no larger one, except by pruning them using the apriori rules? That is my point: the APRIORI algorithm collects probably as much information as you need to make sure you are not *missing* an even larger itemset!

Comment: It depends how you set the minimum support threshold. If you set minsup=0, then obviously the largest itemset is the largest transaction in your dataset. If you set minsup >0  you could use the FPtree and take the longest path in the fptree with a support >= minsup.  That would be more efficient than Apriori which is an inneficient algorithm.  The main problem with Apriori is that it can even generate candidates that do not appear in the database and that it works as a BFS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a line of interesting work on this, based on the FP-Tree datastructure. The approach is described in a nice [paper from 2008](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.ins.2007.08.006), and it was [extended in 2011](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/KSE.2011.18) by adding new pruning techniques.

Answer (score 1):

Build an FPTree and at the same time as you construct the tree, record the longest tree path(s) such that the support  >= minsup.

This would give you the largest itemset(s).

If minsup =0, then the largest itemset(s) are the largest transaction(s).